# Connect 4 implemented with python AI alpha-beta-pruning (Recursion/MemoryError)?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm trying to create a game called Connect Four with AI which uses the alpha-beta pruning algorithm in python. Here is the code I have managed to write:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

class ConnectFour:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board  = [[],[],[],[],[],[]]
        for i in range(7):
            for j in range(6):
                self.board[j].append(" ")
        self.moves = 0
        self.colstack = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        self.node = 0
        self.move = 0

    def PrintGameBoard(self):
        print('  0   1   2   3   4   5   6')
        for i in range(5, -1, -1):
            print('|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|')
            print("| ",end="")
            for j in range(7):
                print(self.board[i][j],end="")
                if j != 6:
                    print(" | ",end="")
                else:
                    print(" |")
        print('`---------------------------´')

    def CanPlay(self, col):
        return self.colstack[col] < 6

    def Play(self, col, board):
        board[self.colstack[col]][col] = 2
        self.colstack[col] += 1
        self.moves += 1
        return board

    def IsWinning(self, currentplayer):
        for i in range(6):
            for j in range(4):
                if self.board[i][j] == currentplayer and self.board[i][j+1] == currentplayer and self.board[i][j+2] == currentplayer and self.board[i][j+3] == currentplayer:
                    return True
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(7):
                if self.board[i][j] == currentplayer and self.board[i+1][j] == currentplayer and self.board[i+2][j] == currentplayer and self.board[i+3][j] == currentplayer:
                    return True     
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(4):
                if self.board[i][j] == currentplayer and self.board[i+1][j+1] == currentplayer and self.board[i+2][j+2] == currentplayer and self.board[i+3][j+3] == currentplayer:
                    return True
        for i in range(3,6):
            for j in range(4):
                if self.board[i][j] == currentplayer and self.board[i-1][j+1] == currentplayer and self.board[i-2][j+2] == currentplayer and self.board[i-3][j+3] == currentplayer:
                    return True
        return False

    def AlphaBeta(self, alpha, beta):
        self.node += 1
        if self.moves == 42:
            return 0
        for col in range(7):
            if self.CanPlay(col) and self.IsWinning(2):
                return (43 - self.moves)/2  
        max = (41 - self.moves)/2
        if beta > max:
            beta = max
            if alpha >= beta:
                return beta
        for col in range(7):
            if self.CanPlay(col):
                self.board[self.colstack[col]][col] = 2
                self.move = col
                score = -self.AlphaBeta(-alpha, -beta)
                if score >= beta:
                    return score
                elif score > alpha:
                    alpha = score
                self.board[self.colstack[col]][col] = " "

    def Solve(self, table, week=False):
        self.node = 0
        self.board = table
        if week:
            self.AlphaBeta(-1, 1)
            self.board = self.Play(self.move, table)
            return self.board
        else:
            self.AlphaBeta(-21, 21)
            self.board = self.Play(self.move, table)
            return self.board

    def PlayerMove(self, table):
        self.board  = table
        try:
            allowedmove = False
            while not allowedmove:
                print("Choose a column where you want to make your move (0-6): ",end="")
                col =input()
                if self.CanPlay(int(col)):
                    self.board[self.colstack[int(col)]][int(col)] = 1
                    self.moves += 1
                    self.colstack[int(col)] += 1
                    allowedmove = True
                else:
                    print("This column is full")
        except (NameError, ValueError, IndexError, TypeError, SyntaxError) as e:
            print("Give a number as an integer between 0-6!")
        else:
            return self.board

def PlayerMark():
    print("Player 1 starts the game")
    mark = ''
    while not (mark == "1" or mark == "2"):
        print('Do you want to be 1 or 2: ',end="")
        mark = input()
    if mark == "1":
        return 1
    else:
        return 2

def PlayAgain():
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no) :',end="")
    return input().lower().startswith('y')

def main():
    sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
    print("Connect4")
    while True:
        mark = PlayerMark()
        connectfour = ConnectFour()
        if mark==1:
            print("You are going to start the game\r\n\r\n")
        else:
            print("Computer (negamax) starts the game")
        gameisgoing = True
        table  = [[],[],[],[],[],[]]
        for i in range(7):
            for j in range(6):
                table[j].append(" ")
        while gameisgoing:
            connectfour.PrintGameBoard()
            if mark == 1:
                table = connectfour.PlayerMove(table)
                if connectfour.IsWinning(1):
                    connectfour.PrintGameBoard()
                    print('You won the game!')
                    gameisgoing = False
                else:
                    if connectfour.moves==42:
                        connectfour.PrintGameBoard()
                        print('Game is tie')
                        break
                    else:
                        mark = 2
            else:
                move = connectfour.Solve(table)
                if connectfour.IsWinning(2):
                    connectfour.PrintGameBoard()
                    print('Computer won the game')
                    gameisgoing = False
                else:
                    if connectfour.moves==42:
                        connectfour.PrintGameBoard()
                        print('Game is tie')
                        break
                    else:
                        mark = 1
        if not PlayAgain():
            print("Game ended")
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm not sure if the algorithm is working properly, but the problem is that I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` in comparison. If I increase `recursionlimit` I get in around 10000 `MemoryError: Stack Overflow`. I think that the problem is that there is too many states to handle for my computer. That's why I changed the negamax algorithm to alpha-beta pruning, but there seem to be still to many states. Is there a effective technique that does algorithmic search, for example max depth 10 and still the computer is almost invincible? I'm waiting your solutions.

Comment: I found out that I need to use somekind of cutoff search (maybe in deep 4 or 5) and evaluation function. Is it hard to modify my alpha-beta pruning function to this kind of behavior?

Comment: I upgraded my code and alphabetapruning algorithm in where use min and max functions + evaluation function but there is some problems when I try to unmake move. If someone expert knows whats really happens I will be very thankful. Otherwise this is going to be a monolog. Code https://pastebin.com/uQBMYVLK

Comment: I finally manage to do alphabetapruning algorithm to connect4 but my evaluation function is not enough powerful because it sometimes make stupid moves when it can easily avoid the lose... I can post here the code and if someone have idea how to improve my code it would be nice. Code: https://pastebin.com/xb5a3zX8

Comment: I applaud you writing your own negamax algorithm. Doing so creates good insight into how the algorithm works. If helpful, there is an existing python library that implements Negamax and some variants called [easyAI](http://zulko.github.io/easyAI/). One of them is a non-recursive version that is pretty much immune to the problem described. It might also be faster. There are also docs on how to improve performance using methods such as transposition tables.